# Add Taxonomy Tags to uploaded images

Tags: 7, views, nodes, taxonomy-terms, media

Is there any way to add the taxonomy term reference (tags) for each image uploaded? It just has 'alt tags' and title as default...

So far I can just add tags for a set of images (albums) but I want to be able to tag each of the images separately - one by one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by installing and configuring [Taxonomy Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image) module.

> The taxonomy_image module allows site administrators to associate
>   images with taxonomy terms. With the association created, an admin can
>   then make a call to 'taxonomy_image_display()' from their theme or
>   other PHP code to display the appropriate image.

Please follow this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/101682) as well.

Comment: I will try that later - I have D7 does it work with the D7 DEV version?

Comment: Yes. It should work.